# Generating lenses for a "lens" library with a custom name processor instead of the default "underscore"-based one

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, lenses, haskell-lens

The standard [`makeLenses`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens/3.9.0.2/doc/html/Control-Lens-TH.html#v%3amakeLenses) implementation generates lenses for all the fields of a record which begin with underscore. I very much dislike the idea of having to introduce such an awkward naming convention to my records for many reasons. What I want to do is just generate lenses for all fields of a record and name them by just appending a suffix "L" to field names.

With an *fc-labels* library all I had to do to achieve that was

```
mkLabelsWith (++ "L") [''MyRecord]
```

but the *lens* library has a much more involved configuration with [rulesets](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens/3.9.0.2/doc/html/Control-Lens-TH.html#t%3aLensRules) and stuff, which isn't as easy to get a mind around. So I'm asking for a specific recipe to just achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looking at the code, it seems pretty straightforward. `LensRules` have a function `lensField :: String -> Maybe String` (which either gives the name for a lens or fails). So you can make a function like

```
myMakeLenses = makeLensesWith $ lensRules
  & lensField .~ (\name -> Just (name ++ "L"))
```

and use that instead of `makeLenses`. Of course you could parameterize your function on `(++ "L")`.

Or you could write it inline if you prefer, e.g.

```
makeLensesWith ?? ''Foo $ lensRules
  & lensField .~ (\name -> Just (name ++ "L"))
```

(Note that `(??)` is just infix `flip` for passing the arguments in the right order. You can think of it as a "hole" in this case that the second argument get filled into. And `(&)` is just flipped `($)`.)

Comment: note that this is now broken with lens-4.4 which has modified the template-haskell related code.

Answer (score 19):

shachaf's answer doesn't work with lenses 4.4+ which changed the template-haskell related APIs.

Here is the implementation that works with those versions:

```
import Language.Haskell.TH

myMakeLenses :: Name -> DecsQ
myMakeLenses = makeLensesWith $ lensRules
    & lensField .~ \_ _ name -> [TopName (mkName $ nameBase name ++ "L")]
```

(this is 4.5+, in 4.4 the lambda would take only `\_ name` as parameters)